# Abrir la aplicación en un activity en especifico después de provocar su cierre

Tags: android

Buen día

Tengo la siguiente duda, estoy generando una app en android que tiene 5 pantallas 
A, B, C , D y E. Si en la pantalla C la app se cierra ya sea por que el usuario lo decide así o por el sistema, la aplicación al abrir nuevamente debe abrir en el punto C y al hacer back regresar nuevamente a B

Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar de antemano gracias
Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas compañero Leo, sobre tu duda podrías crear un tabla en un base de datos e ir manteniendo actualizada la ultima ventana que el usuario tuvo abierta, pero en android tenemos también un objeto que te ayudara con esto que se llama SharedPreferences, es mas fácil de implementar y solo te creara un archivo .xml en tu directorio del cual podrás tomar los datos siempre que quieras, la idea seria que,a pesar que podría ser un poco tedioso, en el oncreate() de todas tus actividades guardes en tu SharedPreferences la ventana que esta abierta, luego si el usuario cierra la app o se detiene por cualquier motivo en tu actividad principal o por así decirlo en la que se ejecuta al inicio verifiques que ventana dice que fue la ultima que abrió el usuario en tu SharedPreferences, simplemente remplazarias tu valor en el SharedPreferences  cada que tu usuario abra un activite, te dejo un ejemplo de un forma de implementarlo.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
guardarPreferencias();
}

//guardar configuración aplicación Android usando SharedPreferences
public void guardarPreferencias(){
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("preferenciasMiApp", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putBoolean("preferenciasGuardadas", true);
editor.putString("preferencia1", "Hola estoy guardando esto");
editor.putString("preferencia2", "y tambien esto");
editor.commit();
Toast.makeText(this, "guardando preferencias", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

//cargar configuración aplicación Android usando SharedPreferences
public void cargarPreferencias(){
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("preferenciasMiApp", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
this.preferencias1 = prefs.getString("preferencia1", "valor por defecto");
this.preferencias2 = prefs.getString("preferencia1", "valor por defecto");
preferenciasGuardadas = prefs.getBoolean("preferenciasGuardadas", false);

}
```

Enlace del ejemplo: http://www.tutorialandroid.com/basico/como-guardar-preferencias-en-mi-aplicacion-con-sharedpreferences-sin-usar-base-de-datos/

En este ejemplo guardamos dos preferencias, te lo comento por si te confundió.
Referente a la segunda parte de tu pregunta, sobre hacer que al apretar back o atrás vaya a la pantalla anterior, esto lo puedes hacer con el método.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
     // Añade más funciones si fuese necesario
     verificar_preferencia();
     ejectuar_actividad();
     super.onBackPressed();  // Invoca al método
}
```

Perdón por explayarme tanto en mi respuesta, comentar si te ayudo en algo o si tienes alguna duda.